# PHP Warning: Unknown list entry type (32580) in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.1

After upgrading my project from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.1, I'm getting this warning continuously in error log file. I'm unable to trace since it comes after my page gets loaded.

```
PHP Warning: Unknown list entry type (32580) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: We cannot trace it either. Lot's of info [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=PHP+Warning%3A+Unknown+list+entry+type+(32580)+in+Unknown+on+line+0&oq=PHP+Warning%3A+Unknown+list+entry+type+(32580)+in+Unknown+on+line+0&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.445j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have tried to search on google before putting here. But I didn't found proper solution for this kind of warning.

Comment: @JayBlanchard If you have encontered same issue then can you please share the link.

Comment: @AnilGupta I am also facing same issue on my PHP7 environment after upgrading PHP version. It's pathetic issue.

Comment: Have you considered the code in the page that gets loaded? That is the code we'd need to see before we could even begin to guess what is causing the warning. Just providing an error will not get you an answer, we *must* see the code which may be causing the error. None of us have crystal balls.

Comment: It looks like a generic error, hence I have posted.